# Excel 2010: How to filter a pivot table based on a list in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have 2 Excel sheets, The first one containing a pivot table with many columns and the second sheet containing only one column. I'm looking for a way to make the second sheet to be used as a filter in my Pivot Table.

I tried to connect two pivot tables but they should be created from the same data source.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal details you have provided, I can think of some thing like below.

If you say filter in pivot means it should be associated with the data column/columns(for the pivot). So add this field to the data sheet you wish to pivot so that this will be available inside the pivot itself.

Comment: My data source is SQL Server so, I can't modify it